# Utilizar classes de um .java no .java principal

Tags: java, funções, import

Boa tarde, estou começando a estudar Java e me deparei com um desafio.

Tenho o código 1 com a minha main

```
package A2_09Fev;

import static A2_09Fev.Atividade1.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A2_09Fev {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        soma();
        media();
        operacoesAritmeticas();
    };
}
```

E criei uma classe Atividade1.java para desenvolver minhas funções

```
public class Atividade1 {
    
    public static void soma(){
    
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double a, b, soma;
        
        System.out.println("Insira dois valores a serem somados: ");
        
        a = ler.nextDouble();
        b = ler.nextDouble();
        
        soma = a + b;
        
        System.out.println("Soma: "+soma);
    
    };
    
    public static void media(){
        
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double a, b, c, media;
        
        System.out.println("Insira 3 números: ");
        
        a = ler.nextDouble();
        b = ler.nextDouble();
        c = ler.nextDouble();
        
        media = (a + b + c) / 3;
        
        System.out.println("A média é: "+media);
    
    };
    
    public static void operacoesAritmeticas(){
        
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double v1, v2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;
        
        System.out.println("Insira dois valores: ");
        
        v1 = ler.nextDouble();
        v2 = ler.nextDouble();
        
        soma = v1 + v2;
        subtracao = v1 - v2;
        multiplicacao = v1 * v2;
        divisao = v1 / v2;
        
        System.out.println("Soma: " +soma);
        System.out.println("Subtração: "+subtracao);
        System.out.println("Multiplicação: "+multiplicacao);
        System.out.println("Divisão: "+divisao);
        
    };

}
```

Ambas estão dentro do mesmo pacote, que é o **A2_09Fev**, acontece que a unica maneira de conseguir utilizar minhas funções foi importando elas dessa maneira, com o "public" logo após o import, e não sei se essa é a maneira mais correta, queria saber se há algo que eu estou fazendo errado fazendo dessa maneira, o código funciona, mas acredito que não esteja certo. Também queria saber qual a maneira mais correta de declarar uma função.

Obs.: poderia sim fazer todo o código do arquivo Atividade1.java dentro da minha main sem funções, porém já sei que futuramente precisarei de funções e classes então resolvi me aventurar nesse desafio.

Answer (score 1):

Você está trabalhando com modificadores de acesso.

No caso de Classes top-level:

- `public`: pode ser acessada em qualquer lugar
- sem modificador: package-private, ou seja, só pode ser acessada dentro do pacote

No caso de membros de uma classe (métodos e variáveis) essa imagem define bem os modificadores de acesso que você pode colocar.
`public` - pode ser acessado em qualquer lugar
`protected` - pode ser acessado pela própria classe, outras classes dentro do próprio pacote, e subclasses da classe em questão
`sem modificador (default)` - nesse caso você deixa sem modificador, ele vai poder ser acessado pela própria classe e classes dentro do mesmo pacote
`private` - só pode ser acessado pela própria classe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]